# Query not returning data within the last 3 years

Tags: sqlite

I want to get all of the data within the last 3 years based on the column filedate

Current query:

```
SELECT casename, filedate
FROM CourtCases
WHERE filedate >= date('now') -3;
```

The result of this query:

[image: Clearly it doesn't work]

Clearly this doesn't work. The result should be all cases from 2015-2018

Comment: @peterm Initially I had it as a varchar(20), which was my mistake, but currently it is a DATE type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place -3 inside the `date` function:

```
SELECT casename, filedate
FROM CourtCases
WHERE filedate >= date('now', '-3 years');
```

EDIT: Fixed, see comments below.

Comment: So I tried it out, and it returned what I have in my description. Could it be a problem with how the date was entered into the database? The format MM/DD/YYYY is fine right?

Comment: @SPYBUG96 No, it's correct with a space after the number, see: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: @SPYBUG96 The correct date format is the ISO8601: YYYY-MM-DD, you can use this query to convert the data(make a backup first!): http://amin-ahmadi.com/2015/05/29/how-to-convert-date-formats-in-sqlite/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT casename, filedate
FROM CourtCases
WHERE filedate>=date('now','-3 year');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. Could it be a problem with how the field was entered into the database?